# AND and OR in Mongo Query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using multiple operators in this query. I get no syntax errors, but I'm not getting any data back (and should be), so I'm pretty certain that I'm looking at a logical error. Problem is, I don't see it.

**Query:**

```
db.questions.find(
    {'$and': [
        {'answers.s_user_id': {'$ne': s_user_id}},
        {'$or': [
                {'s_text': re.compile(s_term, re.IGNORECASE)},
                {'choices': re.compile(s_term, re.IGNORECASE)}
        ]}
    ]}
)
```

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found the issue as documented here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2585

Nested $OR is not supported until MongoDB 1.9.1 as of 7-24-2011. I'm on an older version.

Comment: To add to your findings, your query is equivalent to db.questions.find(
    { 'answers.s_user_id': {'$ne': s_user_id}},
        {$or: [
                {'s_text': re.compile(s_term, re.IGNORECASE)},
                {'choices': re.compile(s_term, re.IGNORECASE)}
        ]}
    }
)

Answer (score 0):

```
Please find the query
AND Queries With Multiple Expressions Specifying the Same Operator

Consider the following example:

db.inventory.find( {
    $and : [
        { $or : [ { price : 0.99 }, { price : 1.99 } ] },
        { $or : [ { sale : true }, { qty : { $lt : 20 } } ] }
    ]
} )
```